# Why do we have to access DOM value within function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

view my code

[image]

This code doesn't work if I put variable x outside the function like this. In this case, it wouldn't alert my input value, but the initial value which is null in this case. The error is fixed if I put x inside the function. Does anyone know why?

Thanks so much!

Comment: where is the code buddy?

Comment: Please no images of code.

Comment: And you really shouldn't be using w3schools.com. Their content is awfully out of date!

Comment: var would work without error even if it's inside or outside. can you tell what is the error?

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+input+value+empty+when+variable+outside+function) of [Can't retrieve value from input form outside function](/q/46155059/4642212).

Comment: Inline event handlers like `onclick` are [not recommended](/q/11737873/4642212). They are an [obsolete, hard-to-maintain and unintuitive](/a/43459991/4642212) way of registering events. Always [use `addEventListener`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these) instead.

Comment: And the reason it does not work is the line is executed when the page is getting loaded. But when you click on button, it will simply show last value from x

Answer (score 1):

You're reading the value before the user enters it.

Here's your program:

1. x is "".
2. User clicks something
3. Alert x (which is "").
4. Basically alert("").

If you place it in the function, the value is read as soon as the user clicks something. Because they're both part of the same synchronous operation, there's no delay.

But if your function is *asynchronous*, there's a problem. The user can change it in the background.

So read it when it is being clicked.